# example programme to create a pair of random bright and dark hex color codes

Tags: go, backend

In my app I have a text and a background box surrounding the text. what i want is  to assign colors for both of them. now i randomly creates one of the colors  by following method

```
    R: uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
    G: uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
    B: uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
```

now i adopted a method to create compatible hex color by following method

```
    R: 255 - color.R,
    G: 255 - color.G,
    B: 255 - color.B,
```

but colors are not compatible by this method.
i think one of the color should be dark and other should be lighter. i saw in stackoverflow to calculate lumninance for determining a color is dark or light. but i dont get a correct method for this. in short i want a programme for creating two hex color codes which are compatible.

Comment: How do you define "compatible"? Also note that your algorithm cannot give "good" results in all cases, what if the random color is `127, 127, 127`? The result would be `128, 128, 128`, an almost identical color.

Comment: yes , your example case is also a problem. by compatible i mean that when we display the text and the background box in the screen it cannot be distinguished if both of the colors are bright or dark

Comment: You most likely need to develop a more in-depth algorithm to determine this. Here is a ux exchange article that may help https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82056/how-to-measure-the-contrast-between-any-given-color-and-white/82068#82068

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the following code:
( **NOTICE** : brightness = (0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B) / 255 )

```golang
type Color struct {
    R uint8
    G uint8
    B uint8
}

func generateRandomColor() Color {
    return Color{
        R: uint8(rand.Intn(256)),
        G: uint8(rand.Intn(256)),
        B: uint8(rand.Intn(256)),
    }
}

func calculateBrightness(color Color) float64 {
    return (0.299*float64(color.R) + 0.587*float64(color.G) + 0.114*float64(color.B)) / 255
}

func generateCompatibleColors() (Color, Color) {
    color1 := generateRandomColor()
    color2 := Color{
        R: 255 - color1.R,
        G: 255 - color1.G,
        B: 255 - color1.B,
    }

    brightness1 := calculateBrightness(color1)
    brightness2 := calculateBrightness(color2)

    if brightness1 > brightness2 {
        color1, color2 = color2, color1
    }

    return color1, color2
}

func colorToHex(color Color) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("#%02X%02X%02X", color.R, color.G, color.B)
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    color1, color2 := generateCompatibleColors()

    fmt.Printf("RGB : Color 1 : %v, Color 2 : %v\n", color1, color2)
    fmt.Printf("HEX : Color 1 : %v, Color 2 : %v", colorToHex(color1), colorToHex(color2))
}
```

Comment: basically you mean after finding their brightness the color having more brightness is set as text color and less brightness is set as background color .  that also good idea. but i indent to generate two colors which are complementary , which means the two colors generated should be very different and complementary so that user can easily read the text without any difficulty of the backgrround color